# scale_fill_manual define color for NA values

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, na

I try to make a barplot with ggplot2 and am facing some issues with defining the color for NA.

```
ggh <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=var1, fill=var2))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(
    values=c("s"="steelblue", "i"="darkgoldenrod2", "r"="firebrick4", na.value="black"))
```

In my var2 I have values `c("s", "i", "r", NA)`. For some reason my code above inside the `scale_fill_manual` does not work for NA, even if it works fine for all the others values.

Can someone help me figure out why?

Thanks for the help

Comment: try `scale_fill_manual(values=c("s"="steelblue", "i"="darkgoldenrod2", "r"="firebrick4"), na.value="black")`

Comment: arg `values` doesn't include the arg `na.value` so close the vector of `values`

Comment: Thank you, it was so simple ^^

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `na.value` needs to be outside of the `values` argument.  Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

mydata <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 150, replace = TRUE),
                     var2 = sample(c("s", "i", "r", NA), 150, replace = TRUE))

ggplot(mydata) +
  aes(x = var1, fill = var2) +
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("s" = "steelblue",
                               "i" = "darkgoldenrod2",
                               "r" = "firebrick4"),
                    na.value = "black")
```

[image]