# scale_color_manual define multiple colors for NA values causes multi color lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have data where I want to plot bar charts and line plots with the same color scheme associated with values of var2. However, there are a number of values for var2 that only occur occasionally. Rather than find the names for all of these and explicitly code them into the color scale I would like to set the na.value to a few colors that can be used in case there are multiple values that don't match a name. 
Here is some example data adapted from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144630/scale-fill-manual-define-color-for-na-values).

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

mydata <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 150, replace = TRUE),
                     var2 = sample(c("s", "i", "y", "x"), 150, replace = TRUE),
                     var3 = sample(1:10,150,replace = TRUE))

my_cols <- c("s" = "steelblue",
             "i" = "darkgoldenrod2",
             "z" = "red",
             "c" = "pink")
```

This works well for producing a bar chart

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = var1, fill = var2)) +
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "var2",
                    values = my_cols,
                    na.value = c("black","green"))
```

[image: bargraph]

However, when I use the same theory applied to geom_line it colors each line segment differently.

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = var2, y = var3, col = var2))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "var2",
                    values = my_cols,
                    na.value = c("black","green","cyan"))
```

[image: linegraph]

Any idea how I could get the two lines to take one color from na.value for their whole length?

Side note: If one doesn't supply a color for `na.value` it plots the graph with empty space where the na value should be. This can be very confusing, maybe there could be a helpful warning message?

Comment: If you're using a manual color scale, why not supply it with enough colors to fit the categories? Or why not use `scale_fill_discrete`? On the line chart, maybe you need to set a group?

Comment: I have a specific color palette that I want to use. The one in the question is just an example and I need it to be the same across different plots with different datasets that have different values for var2. Setting group did not change anything. There are a number of values for var2 that only occur occasionally. Rather than find the names for all of these and explicitly code them into the color scale I would like to set the na.value to a few colors that can be used in case there are multiple values that don't match a name.