# Include NA values in plot and size, fill legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, na

I have NA values in a data set, which I would like to include in my ggplot as well as in the legend. I thought this would be easily done by specifying the `na.values="somecolour"` option, as shown e.g. in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144630/scale-fill-manual-define-color-for-na-values) post. However, for my example the code runs without plotting any of the NAs, nor including an entry in the legend. Instead rows with missing values are automatically removed. Here's some code for illustration:

```
set.seed(42)  
lat <- rnorm(10, 54, 12)
long <- rnorm(10, 44, 12)
val <- rnorm(6, 10, 3)
val <- c(val,NA,NA,NA,NA)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(long, lat, val))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=lat, y=long, size=val, fill=val),shape=21,alpha=0.6) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 12), breaks=pretty_breaks(4)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(direction = -1, palette="RdYlBu", breaks=pretty_breaks(4),na.value = "black") +     
  guides(fill = guide_legend(), size = guide_legend()) +
  theme_minimal()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem comes from setting `size` in `aes` as you can't set size for `NA` values in `scale_size_continuous`.

My solution would be to **plot NA values separately** (not perfect, but works). To add them to legend set some dummy value within `aes` to call there guide.

However, there is a problem that `NA` legend doesn't align nicely with non-NA legend. To adjust the alignment we have to plot another set of invisible `NA` values with the size of maximum non-NA values.

```
ggplot(df, aes(lat, long, size = val, fill = val)) +
    geom_point(shape = 21,alpha = 0.6) +
    geom_point(data = subset(df, is.na(val)), aes(shape = "NA"),
               size = 1, fill = "black") +
    geom_point(data = subset(df, is.na(val)), aes(shape = "NA"),
               size = 14, alpha = 0) +
    scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 12), breaks = pretty_breaks(4)) +
    scale_fill_distiller(direction = -1, palette = "RdYlBu", breaks = pretty_breaks(4)) +     
    labs(shape = "         val\n",
         fill = NULL,
         size = NULL) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(), 
           size = guide_legend(),
           shape = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.4, "cm"))
```

[image]

PS: requires `ggplot2_3.0.0`.

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas for your suggestion. However, that is more or less where I started (see my previvious question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100240/merging-legends-of-separate-layers-in-ggplot)). My aim ist to have all the information in one legend, but it seems that ggplot does not make this easy...

Comment: @M.Teich Is there any way I can improve my current answer?